# How to wait for Room database to update before calling a function?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

I am removing some data within a Room database table. After the data is removed I would like to call a function. The function should not be called until after the data has been removed. The problem is that the function to remove is asynchronous so the function is called before the db is updated.

```
onEndSession(){
   myViewModel.removeAllData()
   showSplashScreen()
}
```

In this example, I want to call `showSplashScreen()` after the data has been removed.

Comment: Without knowing what `removeAllData()` looks like and how it ties into "the function to remove is asynchronous", it will be difficult for anyone to help you. My guess is that `showSplashScreen()` really should be triggered by a `LiveData<Event<...>>` in the `ViewModel`, following the "single live event" pattern. You would have the `ViewModel` post the event once the background work completed.

Comment: please add an implementation of  `myViewModel.removeAllData()`,

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Event class like this -

```
open class Event<out T>(private val content: T) {

var hasBeenHandled = false
    private set // Allow external read but not write

/**
 * Returns the content and prevents its use again.
 */
fun getContentIfNotHandled(): T? {
    return if (hasBeenHandled) {
        null
    } else {
        hasBeenHandled = true
        content
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the content, even if it's already been handled.
 */
fun peekContent(): T = content
}
```

Inside your ViewModel -

```
private val showSplash = MutableLiveData<Event<Boolean>>()

fun getShowSplash(): LiveData<Event<Boolean>>{
   return showSplash
}

// Assuming you are using asynchronous task to remove all data
fun removeAllData(){
   // If you are using AsyncTask then in onComplete() call
   showSplash.value = true
}

// If you are using Kotlin Co-routines then do this
fun removeAllData(){
   viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
     //Whatever implementation you have of removeAllData() then put this code
       withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
           showSplash.value = true
       }
   }
}
```

In your activity or fragment where you have showSplashScreen() put this code

```
mainViewModel.getShowSplash().observe(this, Observer {
        it.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let {showSplash ->
             if(showSplash != null && showSplash) 
                showSplashScreen() 
        }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

with [rxjava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) you can write this action whit `completable` like this

```
//viewModel
fun removeAllData(): Completable {
    return Completable.fromAction {
        removeData()
    }
}


//in Activity
fun startDelete(){
mainViewModel()
.removeAllData()
.observeOn(AndroidMainThread).subscribe(
                        {
                            showSplashScreen()
                        },
                        {
                          e(it)

                        }
                    )
}
```